# I need to make a bag using a Doubly Linked List with (element, frequency) pairs

Tags: c++

Just like in the title, I need to make a bag using a Doubly Linked List with (element, frequency) pairs. By analyzing other projects I made, so far i made this:

```
//bag.h
#pragma once
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
//DO NOT INCLUDE BAGITERATOR
//DO NOT CHANGE THIS PART
#define NULL_TELEM -111111;
typedef int TElem;
class BagIterator; 
class Bag {

private:
    struct node
    {
        pair<TElem, int> info;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    node* tail;

    friend class BagIterator;
public:
    //constructor
    Bag();
    //adds an element to the bag
    void add(TElem e);
    //removes one occurence of an element from a bag
    //returns true if an element was removed, false otherwise (if e was not part of the bag)
    bool remove(TElem e);
    //checks if an element appearch is the bag
    bool search(TElem e) const;
    //returns the number of occurrences for an element in the bag
    int nrOccurrences(TElem e) const;
    //returns the number of elements from the bag
    int size() const;
    //returns an iterator for this bag
    BagIterator iterator() const;
    //checks if the bag is empty
    bool isEmpty() const;
    //destructor
    ~Bag();
```

and

```
//bag.cpp

#include "Bag.h"
#include "BagIterator.h"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Bag::Bag() {
    //TODO - Implementation
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;
}
void Bag::add(TElem elem) {
    //node* n;
    //n = new node;
    //n->pair.first = elem;
    //dont know how to do it/continue it.
}
```

So basically I have no idea how to implement the add() function. I think I can make the other functions like remove() and search() if I had add() as a model, but since I also need to keep count of the frequency, trial and error hasn't got me anywhere.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<std::pair<TElem, int>>`?  The Bag doesn't appear to add any value over a standard C++ library vector.

Comment: `TElem` is not defined anywhere, and "etc" is not a valid way to end a class definition. Post real code.

Comment: @Eljay smells like an assignment... prolly not allowed to use any real C++. you now how "professors" are... edit: the edit confirms it: he/she/they got a template...

Comment: @Eljay even with a vector, not sure how to tackle the frequency part. Pete i fixed it. JHBonarius you're right, but i can try to translate the real c++ code into "data structures" 's one. Either way, i just need a foundation to analyze and understand

Comment: Just copy some online example e.g. [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/). But ALWAYS obfuscate it, because professors also have google and don't like you copying oniine examples. Or do your homework, read your book, think about it, and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
void add(TElem elem) {
        node* n = nullptr;
        n = new node;
        n->info.first = elem;
        if (this->tail == nullptr) { //if we don't have an end
            if (this->head == nullptr) { //if we dont have a start
                this->head = n; //set the start to n
            }
            this->tail = n; //set the end to n
        }
        else {
            this->tail->next = n; //our bag's end's next node equals n;
            n->prev = this->tail; //n's previous equals our current tail
            this->tail = this->tail->next; //our tail equals n
        }
    }
```

It adds an element to the end of the bag. I also made a deletion function:

```
bool remove(TElem e) {
        if (this->head == nullptr||this->tail==nullptr) return false; //if we have no elements
        node* traverser = this->head; //our starting point is our bag's starting point
        while (true) {
            if (traverser->info.first == e) { //if we found our element
                node* last = traverser->prev; //the element before ours
                node* succ = traverser->next; //the element after ours
                last->next = succ; //put the element before our's 's next element to the element after our's
                succ->prev = last; //set the element after our's 's previous element to the element before our's
                delete traverser; //delete our element
                return true; 
            }
            else
                if (traverser->next == nullptr) return false; //If we reached the end
                else traverser = traverser->next; //move forward
        }
    }
```

Also, I recommend you add this constructor to your `node` class:

```
node() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
```

Just so that no errors arise.

Also, if you're interested, perhaps this model for an iterator will work for you:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OOqm3ZnUc0ah-etI6ZbCuo41S0f_czoYcSOLwaNIQzM/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: That constructor should be `node() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}`. In this code it doesn't make much difference, but the compiler will always generate code to initialize data members that you don't initialize in the initializer list. That can be expensive. Get in the habit of always initializing members in the initializer list.

Comment: @PeteBecker I will change that

Comment: Hey, thanks Eduardo. Completely forgot i can use info.first / info.second.. Ahh... Thanks for your help. I believe i got an idea now on how to add/traverse the list. Im little foggy on why we need " our tail equals n " but i will try to reverse engineer some more, visualize it on paint and also take care of the frequency.  Thanks again for your help <3

Comment: @HyperOni, any time! Also, see my edit, I added a possible model for your iterator